# 19.10 HP notebook doesn’t show the external monitor

Tags: drivers, display, 19.10, external-monitor

I have a hp notebook with Ubuntu 19.10, it doesn’t recognize my external display, which is a VGA device, and my laptop is HDMI. 
Also the key in my keyboard responsible for controlling don’t work. I'm pretty sure its missing a driver.

Comment: Please look on the serial number sticker to find the parts model number so we can go to https://support.hp.com/us-en/computer and enter it under _Identify your computer for manuals and specific product information_  so you can provide a link to the specifications for your machine. Alternatively, run `lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)`  and copy the result, then come back here. Either way, click [edit] and paste the result in your question.

Comment: If you are using a converter (vga->hdmi), it may not translate all signals correctly thus laptop doesn't get meaningful data from screen. (is VGA digitial/analog or both and can laptop deal with analog if it's vga is analog only?)  I would boot another system (eg. a 'live') to see if it works there, if it doesn't it adds weight to cable/connector issue. Using a different converter may fix issue